# Determining topic of text

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, nltk, topic-model

I was wondering what I should be looking into if I want to measure the similarity between a paragraph and a corpus of text.

For example, given a paragraph of text and the entire corpus of Data Science StackExchange questions, how would you determine whether that paragraph of text could be classified as a Data Science question?